# Android: Highlight <em> tags in SpannableString

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I've the following code:

```
public static SpannableString getSpannable ( String content )
{
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString ( content );

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile ( "<em>(.*?)</em>" ).matcher ( content );

    while ( m.find () )
    { s.setSpan ( new BackgroundColorSpan ( R.color.colorItalic ), m.start ( 1 ), m.end ( 1 ), 0 ); }

    return s;
}
```

It get all `<em>(.*?)</em>` and set a BackgroundColorSpan to the group one `(.*?)` by your respective position.

It works so well! But the problem is `<em>` also is inside string content... after set all spans, how can I remove `<em>` from a `SpannableString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by using the @K Neeraj Lal help, which I'm so grateful. The point is, his answer didn't work inside the `while` loop. So, I had to create a counter to update char position, after a remove the chars. This was necessary because `Matcher` is linked with `content` variable. So, when it replaces `s` variable it changes your length, but the content variable still have the same lenght (where Matcher is linked to). The solution code is:

```
public static SpannableStringBuilder getSpannable ( String content )
{
    SpannableStringBuilder s = new SpannableStringBuilder ( content );

    String startAt = "<em>";
    String endAt   = "</em>";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile ( startAt + "(.*?)" + endAt ).matcher ( content );

    int counter = 0, length  = startAt.length() + endAt.length();
    int startA, startB, endA, endB;

    while ( m.find () )
    {
        startA = m.start()-counter;
        endA   = m.end(1)-counter;
        startB = m.start(1)-counter;
        endB   = m.end()-counter;

        s.setSpan ( new BackgroundColorSpan ( R.color.colorItalic ), startB, endA, 0 );
        s.replace ( endA, endB, "" );
        s.replace ( startA, startB, "" );

        counter += length;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Anyway, I don't know if it is the best approach.

Comment: Nice approach. I forgot to check with multiple tags. Check my solution too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `SpannableString` use `SpannableStringBuilder` and use the `replace` method.

Try this code,

```
String content = "Yeah, <em>This</em> is bold.";

SpannableStringBuilder s = new SpannableStringBuilder(content);

String startTag = "<em>";
int startTagLength = startTag.length();
String endTag = "</em>";
int endTagLength = endTag.length();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag).matcher(content);

while (m.find()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "" + m.start(1));
    Log.e(TAG, "" + m.end(1));
    s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(R.color.red), m.start(1), m.end(1), 0);
    s.replace(m.end(1), m.end(1) + endTagLength, "");
    s.replace(m.start(1) - startTagLength, m.start(1), "");
}

TextView out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
out.setText(s);
```

**EDIT**

Caique Monteiro Araujo's has mentioned in the comments that it doesn't work for multiple tags. The reason for this is that the string lengths were getting messed up in the second iteration since I was replacing the string within the while loop itself.

I am happy that Caique Monteiro Araujo has found a workaround. The folloing is mine. I used a `TreeMap` to store the (start, end) pairs and replace the tags in another loop. I don't know if this is an overkill.

```
String content = "<em>This</em> is <em>bold</em>.";

SpannableStringBuilder s = new SpannableStringBuilder(content);

String startTag = "<em>";
int startTagLength = startTag.length();
String endTag = "</em>";
int endTagLength = endTag.length();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag).matcher(content);

// TreeMap to store the start and end pair
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> pair = new TreeMap<>();
while (m.find()) {

    // Store the start and end
    pair.put(m.start(1), m.end(1));
    s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(R.color.red), m.start(1), m.end(1), 0);
}

// Use descendingMap to reverse the Map
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> reversePair = pair.descendingMap();

// Replace the tags starting from the last occurrence to avoid messing the length
for (Integer key : reversePair.keySet()) {
    Integer end = reversePair.get(key);
    s.replace(end, end + endTagLength, "");
    s.replace(key - startTagLength, key, "");
}

TextView out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
out.setText(s);
```

Comment: There is something wrong and I can't find where... My code is exactly equals to your and it just replace the first match, the output to the next matches are wrong. For example, I had `This is a <em>test</em> to <em>understand</em> the code.` and I got `This is test to <em>underd</em> the.`

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal I know why it's happening, `while` condition inside the matcher doesn't update the `content` lenght after replace tag to ""... so I had to use a counter! I answred my question with the solution, anyway I don't know if I found the best approach =)

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal I saw your edit but it not worked well too, it's because now you fixed the length problem, but you didn't update the `setSpan` position what makes the `BackgroundColorSpan` stay in a wrong position in the new string after replace.